# C programming nan output

Tags: c, output, nan

I am very much a beginner to programming in C so please help out here. I am trying to write a program that loops asking the user to enter a number, if the number is positive it adds it to the total, and if it is negative it ends the program and displays the average, lowest input, and highest input. Unfortunately no matter what I change with the low and high things I keep getting 'nan' for the low, and whatever the negative number for the high.. please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float input;
    float total;
    float low;
    float high;
    float average;
    int count=0;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter a positive number to continue or a negative number");
    printf(" to stop: ");

    scanf("%f", &input);

    while (input > 0)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        printf("\nPlease enter a positive number to continue or a negative");
        printf(" number to stop: ");
        scanf("%f", &input);
        total = total + input;  

        if ( low < input )
        {
            ( low = input );
        }
        else
        {
            ( low = low );  
        }
    }
    if (input < high)
    {
        (high = input);
    }
    else
    {
        (high = high);
    }

    average = total / count;
    printf("\n\n\nCount=%d",count);
    printf("\n\n\nTotal=%f",total);
    printf("\nThe average of all values entered is %f\n", average);
    printf("\nThe low value entered: %f\n", low);
    printf("\nThe highest value entered: %f\n", high);
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it with gcc and testing it with the numbers 1, 5, 4, then -1 I get the following output

```
Count=3


Total=8.000000
The average of all values entered is 2.666667

The low value entered: nan 

The highest value entered: -1.000000
```

Comment: you might want to initialize your variables.  You are comparing against an unknown when you do `low < input` because you haven't defined low yet.  And the same when you do `input < hi`.  In C, variables aren't initialized by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen victim to garbage values - a common mistake for beginners. Specifically, its happening in these lines -

```
float total;
float low;
float high;
float average;
```

When you write that, the system assigns the variables a memory location. The computer though, is not infinite, so it just uses a memory location that used to be used by something else, but is no longer being used. Most of the time though, the 'something else' doesnt clean up after itself (because it would take a lot of time), so the information that was there is left there, such as `fdaba7e23f`. This is totally meaningless to us, so we call it a garbage value.

You can fix this by initializing the variables, like so -

```
float total=0;
float low;
float high;
float average=0;
```

Note that you will have to add some extra logic for the low variable. Here is one way to do it -

```
printf("\n\nPlease enter a positive number to continue or a negative number");
printf(" to stop: ");

scanf("%f", &input);
low=input;
high=input;

while (input > 0)
....
....
```

As you can see, I just copied your code and added two lines after the first `scanf`.

Comment: I made the changes to the variables giving them values and such, what would be the best way you would suggest  the code block for solving the low and high inputs?

Comment: wouldn't the low = input and high = input before the while statement just make the low and high values print out as the negative number?

Comment: @SalZ. If the first input is a negative number, then yes. And that makes sense because if your only input is a negative number, then your low and your high should be the only input, which is negative. However, if the first input isnt negative then the `if`s in your `while` loop will take care of keeping track of the lows and highs.

Comment: @Ddrin91 that makes a lot more sense now, and i got it work exactly how i was thinking. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I don't know if you have noticed it, your count and total are all screwed up.

Please change the order of execution, apart from the initialization answer given by @Drgin

```
int total = input;
while (input > 0)
{
 printf("\nPlease enter a positive number to continue or a negative");
 printf(" number to stop: ");
 scanf("%f", &input);
 count = count + 1;
 total = total + input;
```